# PHP: How to overwrite values in one array with values from another without adding new keys to the array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with default settings, and one array with user-specified settings. I want to merge these two arrays so that the default settings gets overwritten with the user-specified ones.

I have tried to use `array_merge`, which does the overwriting like I want, but it also adds new settings if the user has specified settings that doesn't exist in the default ones. Is there a better function I can use for this than `array_merge`? Or is there a function I can use to filter the user-specified array so that it only contains keys that also exist in the default settings array?

**Example of what I want**

```
$default = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);
$user = array('b' => 3, 'c' => 4);

// Somehow merge $user into $default so we end up with this:
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 3
)
```

Comment: +1 for editing an example of what you want...

Comment: @gnarf: Thank you, hehe. Got so many answers with what I didn't want so figured I should clearify it a bit :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can actually just add two arrays together (`$user+$default`) instead of using `array_merge`.

If you want to stop any user settings that don't exist in the defaults  you can use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

> Returns an associative array containing all the entries of array1 which have keys that are present in all arguments

### Example:

```
$default = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);
$user = array('b' => 3, 'c' => 4);

// add any settings from $default to $user, then select only the keys in both arrays
$settings = array_intersect_key($user + $default, $default);

print_r($settings);
```

### Results:

```
Array
(
    [b] => 3
    [a] => 1
)
```

The keys/values (and order) are selected first from `$user` in the addition, which is why `b` comes before `a` in the array, there is no `a` in `$user`.  Any keys not defined in `$user` that *are* defined in `$default` will then be added to the end of `$user`.  Then you remove any keys in `$user + $default` that aren't defined in `$default`.

Comment: If a key exists in the `$userSettings` but not in `$defaultSettings`, you would copy it over to `$settings`. He doesn't want that to happen.

Comment: This has the same problem as far as I can see from my tests. If there are any settings in `$userSettings` that are not defined in `$defaultSettings`, then they will be taken also. I want all keys not defined in `$defaultSettings` to be ignored and not present in my final `$settings` array.

Comment: @chad & @svish - Sorry, didn't read that caveat until I had posted already, updated with the solution (and wow, quick commenting ;) )

Comment: Hm... missed the `+ $defaultSettings` at first, but when I added that this totally works :) Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably simplest to just loop over the keys in the default-settings array, if you only want to consider those. So you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($default_settings AS $key => $default_value)
{
    if (array_key_exists($key, $user_settings))
    {
        $combined_settings[$key] = $user_settings[$key];
    }
    else
    {
        $combined_settings[$key] = $default_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, seems like something along these lines will be the way to go. Was just hoping PHP had something more clever up it's sleeve and that I could get to know a new and interesting php function, hehe.

Comment: Well, if you want "clever" I'd go with gnarf's answer. But honestly, if I came across that line of code somewhere, I'd have no clue at all what it was doing. So please add an explanation in a comment if you do use that, for the sanity of future maintainers (including yourself).

Comment: I've seen the pattern I used in Zend Framework stuff, and the first time I said "wtf is this doing", but luckily with PHP is easy enough to go to http://php.net/array_intersect_key and figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($default as $key=>$val){   
  if (isset($user[$key]))
  {
    $settings[$key] = $user[$key];
  } else {
    $settings[$key] = $default[$key];
  } 
}
```

I think this is what you want.

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if a key was not set in the $user_settings array?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($user_settings as $key=>$val){   
    $global_settings[$key] = $val; 
}
```

?

Comment: That does exactly what he said he didn't want it to do.

Comment: Yup, hehe. I don't want anything that doesn't exist in the default array to be added.

Comment: I suppose that could work if I add an `if(isset)`, but I was curious to see if there are any php function that can do it out of the box for me. Especially since there are quite a bit of array related functions that I don't quite understand...